# Reusable XCTests for several products

Tags: xcode, xctest, ios-ui-automation, xcode-ui-testing

I need UI tests for XCode project that is a platfrom for several products. 
It means that some elements are custom for some products. For instance, they can have different colors, text styles, etc. from product to product, or the same element could be visible for one project, but hided for another one.

How can I configure my XCode UI tests to make them reusable for various products? I understand I need different schemas. But what about visability elements, for example? It seems I need to check it inside the UI test code? But I think it would be better to use any config file. Am I right? Does anyone have any ideas? I'd be grateful for all advices.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend building out a suite of test helpers that you use in each of your products. These are generic, parameterized functions, such as logging a user in or adding an item to the shopping cart. Instead of hard coding your UI element representations in these helpers, parameterize the inputs. Then you can use them over and over.

```
func addItemToCart(named: String, saveButtonName: String)
func login(username: String, password: String, submitButtonText: String)
func tapTableCell(imageNamed: String)
```

Once you create a basic scaffolding for navigation you can move on to assertion helpers. Leaving the complex logic in the helpers enables you to reuse them and keep your product-specific tests lean and readable.

```
func assertCurrentScreen(named: String)
func assertHighlightedCell(colorNamed: String)
func assertCartTotal(cents: String, containerIdentifier: String)
```

For all of these functions, I recommend adding two default parameters at the end to note the callers file and line number. If you make any custom assertions you can then [pass these references in to show your failure at the callers line, not the helpers](http://masilotti.com/xctest-helpers/).

```
func assertScreen(titled: String, file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
    if !XCUIApplication().navigationBars[titled].exists {
        XCTFail("Item was not added to cart.", file: file, line: line)
    }
}
```

[image: XCTest Helper Example]

Answer (score 0):

I am using a function at the beginning of each test.

```
class SomeTestsClass: XCTestCase {
    func testSomeTest() {
        var externalConfigVariable_1 = "value for defult test"
        var externalConfigVariable_2 = "value for defult test"

        // here You use the external config to override
        // the default test logc
        if let testConfig = getConfig(for: self.name) {
            // read config parameters here
            externalConfigVariable_1 = testConfig["test_var_1"]
            externalConfigVariable_2 = testConfig["test_var_2"]
            // ..........
        }

        // use the variables as You like
        // ......
    }
}

extension XCTestCase {
    public func getConfig(for name: String?) -> [String: Any]? {
        let nameComponents = name?.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "[", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "]", with: "").components(separatedBy: " ")

        if let fileName = nameComponents?.last {
            let testBundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
            guard let path = testBundle.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "JSON") else {
                return nil
            }

            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: path) {
                if let testConfig = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)) as? [String: Any] {
                    return testConfig
                }
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Here is an example JSON:

```
{
  "test_var_1": "Some var",
  "test_var_2": "Some other var"
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about this, but I doesn't have experience with it. Can you show example for more details?

Comment: I have edited the answer. I have written an example ( a little crude one, but working ) for the get config method. and an example usage.

Comment: Also keep in mind that You can add a `XCTestCase` in all of Your test targets and reuse it.